# Append new column with different string values to different dataframes all at once?

Tags: python, pandas, loops

All I want to do is append a new column 'county' to each of the below dataframes, so that the alameda_ dataframe has a new column ['county'] where all rows say "alameda", the coco_ dataframe has a new column ['county'] where all rows say "coco", etc. Ultimately, with each row labeled with the appropriate county, the goal is to concatenate all the dataframes together.

Current code looks like the following, but clearly the for loop isn't right. How do I iterate through both the list of dataframes as well as the list of strings?

```
dfs = [alameda_,coco_,marin_,napa_,solano_,sonoma_,sf_,sm_,sc_]
county_labels = ['alameda','coco','marin','napa','solano','sonoma','sf','sm','sc']

for i in dfs:
    i['county'] = county_labels
```

Replicable example:

```
alameda = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['foo','bar','baz'], 'col2': ['foo','bar','baz'], 'col3': ['foo','bar','baz']})
coco = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['foo','bar','baz'], 'col2': ['foo','bar','baz'], 'col3': ['foo','bar','baz']})
marin = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['foo','bar','baz'], 'col2': ['foo','bar','baz'], 'col3': ['foo','bar','baz']})

new_df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,you can use python [zip function](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_zip.asp) to zip iterators and iterate over them in same time

```
dfs = [alameda_,coco_,marin_,napa_,solano_,sonoma_,sf_,sm_,sc_]
country_labels = ['alameda','coco','marin','napa','solano','sonoma','sf','sm','sc']

for i,j in zip(dfs,country_labels):
    i['county'] = j
```

Answer (score 1):

Use enumerate:

```
import pandas as pd

alameda = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['foo','bar','baz'], 'col2': ['foo','bar','baz'], 'col3': ['foo','bar','baz']})
coco = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['foo','bar','baz'], 'col2': ['foo','bar','baz'], 'col3': ['foo','bar','baz']})
marin = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['foo','bar','baz'], 'col2': ['foo','bar','baz'], 'col3': ['foo','bar','baz']})

dfs = [alameda,coco,marin]
county_labels = ['alameda','coco','marin']

for i, df in enumerate(dfs):
    df['county'] = county_labels[i]

print(alameda.head())
```

Output for `(print(alameda.head())`:

```
  col1 col2 col3   county
0  foo  foo  foo  alameda
1  bar  bar  bar  alameda
2  baz  baz  baz  alameda
```